# Meteor Mongo BulkOp turning ObjectID into plain object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, bulkinsert

While using Meteor, I sometimes access the underlying Node Mongo driver so I can make bulk updates and inserts.

```
const bulk = Coll.rawCollection().initializeOrderedBulkOp();

bulk.insert({key_id: Mongo.Collection.ObjectID()}); // note key_id is an ObjectID
...

bulk.execute();
```

But the value of the `key_id` fields ends up being the plain subdocument `{_str: '...'}` when I look in the database after the insert.

Is there any way to use bulk operations in Node's Mongo library (whatever it is Meteor uses) and keep ObjectID's as Mongo's ObjectID type?

(There's many posts about the nature of the different ID types, and explaining Minimongo, etc. I'm interested specifically about the bulk operations converting ObjectID's into plain objects, and solving that issue.)

Comment: You are using the `.rawCollection()` which exposes the underlying driver methods. So this is expected. "Bulk" is a native method, and not a wrapped meteor method. If you want the meteor id values you need to supply [`Random.id()`](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/random.html) values instead.

Comment: The ids already exist in production (many docs, for a while now), as type `ObjectId` (like, using `pymongo` to query them, I can do `from bson import ObjectId; ObjectId('7613...');`), so I can't just choose to use `Random.id()` unfortunately. But isn't the bson `ObjectId` a natively supported type in Mongo? Is there actually no way to handle ObjectId's when using bulk operations?

Comment: On a native method you would actually need to grab the native implementation. You should be able to access from the loaded driver through `MongoInternals` or alternately load from the `bson` package ( which is available for all languages ) independently. `Mongo.Collection.ObjectID` is **not** a plain `ObjectId` representation, and is actually a complex object for Meteor internal use. Hence why the native methods don't know how to use the value.

Comment: Oh ok, awesome. So something like `MongoInternals.NpmModule.ObjectID`. Makes sense, I had to do the same thing when using the `aggregation` API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Neil's top-level comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46164896/3391108)

> On a native method you would actually need to grab the native implementation. You should be able to access from the loaded driver through MongoInternals [...]
>
> Mongo.Collection.ObjectID is not a plain ObjectId representation, and is actually a complex object for Meteor internal use. Hence why the native methods don't know how to use the value.

So if you have some field which is an `ObjectId`, and you're using some method of a Meteor Collection's `rawCollection` (for example,

- `.distinct`
- `.aggregate`
- `.initializeOrderedBulkOp`
- `.initializeUnorderedBulkOp`

), you'll want to convert your `ObjectId`'s using

```
const convertedID = new MongoInternals.NpmModule.ObjectID(
  originalID._str
);
// then use in one of the arguments to your function or something
const query = {_id: convertedID};
```

before calling the method on them.